# Cannot start/stop/restart service: MySQL Daemon failed to start

Tags: centos

When trying restart mysqld service I'm getting this erroe:
Cannot start/stop/restart service: MySQL Daemon failed to start.

Anybody have idea how to solve it?
I'm running centos 6.5, from what I see I'm missing file:
/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

mysql error logs

```
    140707 12:09:29 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
140707 12:09:29 [Note] libgovernor.so not found
140707 12:09:29 [Warning] option 'innodb-buffer-pool-size': signed value 2097152 adjusted to 5242880
140707 12:09:29 [Warning] option 'innodb-additional-mem-pool-size': signed value 512000 adjusted to 524288
140707 12:09:29 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140707 12:09:29 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140707 12:09:29 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140707 12:09:29 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
140707 12:09:29 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
140707 12:09:29  InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() failed with EAGAIN. Will make 5 attempts before giving up.
InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() attempt 1 failed.
InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() attempt 2 failed.
InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() attempt 3 failed.
InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() attempt 4 failed.
InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() attempt 5 failed.
140707 12:09:31  InnoDB: Error: io_setup() failed with EAGAIN after 5 attempts.
InnoDB: You can disable Linux Native AIO by setting innodb_use_native_aio = 0 in my.cnf
140707 12:09:31 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot initialize AIO sub-system
140707 12:09:31 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
140707 12:09:31 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
140707 12:09:31 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
140707 12:09:31 [ERROR] Aborting

140707 12:09:31 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

140707 12:09:31 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

thanks for answers but I needed to restore it from backup

Comment: Check mysql error logs

Comment: try and start it interactivly

Comment: try and start it interactivly - how?

Comment: This is not an error log!

Comment: Make sure to check the error log first, if you can't find anything useful, try running it manually:

`/usr/sbin/mysqld &`

be careful when you stop it, use SIGTERM

Comment: sorry, now attached error log

Comment: can you attach "my.cnf" file configurations

Comment: What command are you using to start the service? `service mysqld start`?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an issue with AIO not being able to be setup. It may be because:

1. **Space limitations via quota:** Do you have quotas setup for the user you're starting MySQL with? Try looking at `quota -s`
2. **Space limitations via HD:** Perhaps you're running out of space. Look at `df -h` and see if any drive is close to capacity.
3. **Permission issues:** Does the user you're trying to restart the service with have the appropriate permissions?
4. **Configuration changes:** Did you change configuration recently? As a test, try reverting your configuration in `my.cnf`. You may also want to try disabling AIO with `innodb_use_native_aio = 0` but that is just a workaround really.
5. **Database corruption:** I haven't seen this error pop up due to database corruption but I suppose it is a possibility.

Hope this helps.